# java.lang.NullPointerException caught at mforecastadapter in the onpostexecute method

Tags: android

I have initialized the array adapter in the `MainActivityFragment` where I initialized the adapter with fake data and then tried to update the adapter by getting the data from the server. Getting a null pointer exception on using `mforecastadapter` in the `onPostExecute()` method that is a member method of the inline class `FetchWeatherTask`.

```
package com.example.puneet.sunshine;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.text.format.Time;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
public ArrayAdapter<String> mforecastadapter;
public MainActivityFragment() {

}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,true);
        String[] forecast = {
                "Today - Sunny - 80/66",
                "Tomorrow - Cloudy - 75/55",
                "Weds - Foggy - 86/65",
                "Thurs - Asteroids - 76/43",
                "Fri - Sunny - 87/56",
                "Sat - Foggy - 76/55",
                "Sun - Cloudy - 66/44"
        };
        ArrayList<String> weekforecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecast));
        mforecastadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_forecast_layout, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekforecast);

        ListView l = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView_forecast);
        l.setAdapter(mforecastadapter);

        return rootview;
    }
public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

    /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
   * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
   */
    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */
    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException {

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
        // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
        // properly.

        // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
        // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
        // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

        Time dayTime = new Time();
        dayTime.setToNow();

        // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
        int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

        // now we work exclusively in UTC
        dayTime = new Time();
        int le = weatherArray.length();
        String str = new String(String.valueOf(le));
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,str);

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".
            long dateTime;
            // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
            dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
        }

        for (String s : resultStrs) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
        }
        return resultStrs;

    }

    @Override

    public String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
         // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
         // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
         HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
         BufferedReader reader = null;

         if (params.length == 0) {
             return null;
         }
         // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
         String forecastJsonStr = null;

         try {
             // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
             // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
             // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
             String place = params[0];
             String mode = "json";
             String unit = "metric";
             String count = "7";
             String baseUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q="+place+"&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7";
             String apiKey = "&APPID=" + BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY;
             URL url = new URL(baseUrl.concat(apiKey));
             String o1 = new String(String.valueOf(url));
             Log.v(LOG_TAG,"url="+o1);

             // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
             urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
             urlConnection.connect();

             // Read the input stream into a String
             InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
             if (inputStream == null) {
                 // Nothing to do.
                 Log.v(LOG_TAG,"empty input stream");
                 return null;
             }
             reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

             String line;
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                 // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                 // buffer for debugging.
                 buffer.append(line + "\n");
             }

             if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                 // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                 Log.v(LOG_TAG,"empty buffer");
                 return null;
             }
             forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

             Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast Json string:" + forecastJsonStr);
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
             // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
             // to parse it.
             return null;
         } finally {
             if (urlConnection != null) {
                 urlConnection.disconnect();
             }
             if (reader != null) {
                 try {
                     reader.close();
                 } catch (final IOException e) {
                     Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                 }
             }
         }
         try {
             return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, 7);
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             Log.v(LOG_TAG,"null object");
             Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(mforecastadapter==null){
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"adapter null");
        }
        if(result!=null){
            mforecastadapter.clear();
            for(String s: result){
                mforecastadapter.add(s);
            }
        }
        mforecastadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: And where do you instantiate your FetchWeatherTask? And where do you  execute it?

Comment: fetchweathertask is instantiated in other activity named mainactivity

Comment: Well that is probably the root cause of your problem. Your task is an inner class of your fragment and its trying to access your fragments class fields which may be in god knows which state....Create and start your task in your fragment and be wary of the activity/fragment lifecycle

Comment: thnx solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Run your task below the `setAdapter` code as follows:

```
ListView l = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView_forecast);
 l.setAdapter(mforecastadapter);
 new FetchWeatherTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,inputString);
```

or you can initialize the `mforecastAdapter`

```
if(mforecastadapter==null){
          Log.v(LOG_TAG,"adapter null");
          mforecastadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_forecast_layout, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekforecast);
}
```

and make sure to set this adapter on ListView.

I recommend the **first solution**.

Comment: how will it solve my problem? my problem is that why am i getting adapter as null irrespective of the face that i have initialised it using the fake data above.